# SQL insert into tables from another table by triggers

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-insert

TableA

| Order_No | CHA1 | STA1 | STB1 | CHA2 | STA2 | STB2 | CHA3 | STA3 | STB3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EGR12345 | 88 | 89 | 99 | 78 | 84 | 54 | 63 | 64 | 98 |

TableB

| Order_No | CHA | STA | STB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EGR12345 | 88 | 89 | 99 |
| EGR12345 | 78 | 84 | 54 |
| EGR12345 | 63 | 64 | 98 |

I need to use TableA data auto-insert into TableB by multiple rows with triggers

I already tried the script below but failed.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigUpdate_R_REPORT8] 
   ON  [dbo].[TableA] 
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [TableB]
           ([Order_No], [CHA], [STA], [STB])
    (
      SELECT 
           [Order_No], [CHA1], [STA1], [STB1])
      FROM 
           TableA 
     )
```

Comment: Inside trigger you use `... from inserted`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above code is product specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigUpdate_R_REPORT8] ON [dbo].[TableA] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [TableB] ([Order_No], [CHA], [STA], [STB])
    SELECT [Order_No], [CHA1], [STA1], [STB1] FROM inserted
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Order_No], [CHA2], [STA2], [STB2] FROM inserted
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Order_No], [CHA3], [STA3], [STB3] FROM inserted
END
```

I could not see CHA2, STA2, STB2, CHA3, STA3, STB3 in your code. This one above should work for your situation.

Comment: Nut the triggers  show error as below

Comment: Maximun stored procedure,function,trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit32)

Comment: Edited trigger to handle the insertion of multiple rows from TableA into TableB by using UNION in the SELECT statement to combine multiple sets of columns.